# how to pass data from controller to javascript in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
//controller
public function file_upload(){
         
        $targetPath = "assets/uploads/";
        
            
            $data['targetPath'] = $targetPath;
            $this->load->view('test', $data);
}


//JavaScript in view


                if(percent = 100)
                {
                    $('#progressBar').hide();
                    _("status").innerHTML = tp;
                    
                    console.log(tp);
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in words? Is `$targetPath` supposed to be passed to `tp`?

Comment: yes sir, i want to pass data from controller to tp inside script

Comment: is that possible? it always says that the $targetPath is undefined

Comment: That is not possible given the code you posted: in PHP, `$targetPath` is clearly defined, and in JavaScript there is no mention of `$targetPath`. Please make sure you have a [example]. That said, it is almost certainly a duplicate, but I can't find an exact one; someone likely will. You want to put `json_encode($targetPath)` into data, and put `const targetPath = <?=$targetPath?>;`.